# How to change the default visual studio configurations?

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to change visual studio's default configurations (Debug,Release).
That is, change the configurations so that all new solutions created will be affected.

How is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to change about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odds are you'll have to start tinkering with the files in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates

But I don't see a supported way of doing this. You might be best off writing a macro to add them for you.